# How can I use a variable inside a function, outside the function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, axios

I'm trying to use my `allData` variable so I can use the data inside of it and show it in the return. Can someone help me on how can I use that variable inside of that fetchapi function outside of it.

That URL (random-data-api) has an address, which I need to parse it somehow and print it in the return individually, I'm trying to use `allData.address`, also did `fetchapi.allData.address`. I'm new to this, I've been doing research on how to do it, and I haven't found something that helps.

```
  let allData;

  const fetchapi = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true); // Antes del fecth
      await axios
        .get("https://random-data-api.com/api/v2/addresses")
        .then((response) => {
          setLoading(false); // loading false luego de mostrar la data
          const allData: Response = response.data;
          console.log(allData);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false); // loading false si sale un error
      console.log(error);
    }

    return allData;
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <button onClick={fetchapi}>Fetch Location</button>
        {address ? null : (
          <div
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#c7c7c7",
              display: "flex",
              flexDirection: "column",
              padding: 16,
              margin: 5,
              borderRadius: 20
            }}
          >
            <p>
              <strong>Address: {Adress here from the allData var}</strong>
            </p>
            <p>
              <strong>City:{city here from the allData var}</strong>
            </p>
            <p>
              <strong>Street Name:{...}</strong>
            </p>
            <p>
              <strong>Zipcode:{...}</strong>
            </p>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare a state for storing allData similar to how you did setLoading.

then you can store the response into state
setAllData(response.data)

and use it in address field like allData.address

Comment: What do you recommend? a useState?

Comment: Yes. declare a state 

const [allData, setAllData] = useState(); and then set like

setAllData(response.data)

Comment: I created the State variable, where should i place the ```setAllData(response.data)```?

Comment: inside your axios then function where you are getting the response.

axios.get(url).then((response)=>{
setAllData(response.data)
})

Comment: It worked, i also created a variable ```const data = JSON.stringify(allData);```
But when i pass ```allData``` to the address field, it shows the whole data. How can i specifically put what i want?

Comment: if allData is an object just access it like `allData.address` , `allData.city` likewise

Comment: Instead of telling the user what to do in text and comments it would be better if you wrote the code in the answer itself with a code snippet.